# How Can I Securely Store a SecretKey?

Tags: java, security, encryption, keystore, secret-key

I'm building a basic webapp that takes in a user input and returns an encrypted password.

Problem is, currently the SecretKey I am using is stored in the src for the Java class.  To me, it seems this is risky practice so I'm trying to find a way to safely store my SecretKey.

Doing some research, I found the Java KeyStore class but I'm not entirely sure if this is what I need.  Also, if this is what I need, can you guys point me in the direction of how to implement it, and more importantly, how it works?

Thanks

Edit: From doing a lot of thinking/reading it seems like there really isn't a great solution and really a solution isn't needed so long as your main server is secure, which mine will be, so it's not an issue.

Thank you for all the replies! :)

Comment: There is virtually no difference between all the solutions that comprise the storage of the secret key in the server's hard disk. If the key is on the disk there will always be a moment in which it is copied in the server's memory in unencrypted form.

Comment: Why are you returning passwords in a web application? You should ***never*** do this.

Comment: @gd1 then whats the purpose of KeyStore?

Comment: @user2019260 : the purpose of the KeyStore is both to protect the keys when they are not in use (if the KeyStore is encrypted itself) and to organize interdependent keys in a way that makes them usable (think of chained X.509 certs). If you put your key into the keystore, you'll still have to paste the keystore password somewhere in your code. Your problem cannot be solved by software: this is way   someone invented crypto hardware, smartcards, etc... But don't worry, if your server is secure than your key cannot be safer than that.

Comment: @user2019260 : another possibility is that the whole design of your application can be improved thus removing the need of having such key on your server.

Comment: @gd1 thank you for the feedback.  Unfortunately, I don't know how that would be possible?  My application's sole purpose is to generate an encrypted password and return it to a user so the user can directly send that to support.  

I'm not too sure any other way to do it.

Comment: If someone knows the Secret key and the Encrypted text, are they able to work backward to figure out the plain-text?

Comment: @Darius yes, it's a symmetric key

Comment: If you use a KeyStore, one issue I see is that your code will now contain the password to that KeyStore. Does the key have to be symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Passwords should be stored using one way hash functions that way your system avoids this problem. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Actually the OP can surely improve the overall design of his/her application, but that answer doesn't deal with what he/she is asking and should be posted as a comment, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your encryption key, then there is no secure way to store that key safely in JavaScript. I guess the storage you are talking about its the browsers local storage, which is nothing more then a persistent cookie on browser side.
Everybody that uses the chrome WebInspector or Firefox Firebug can easly read this store for any page he is visiting. Furthermore, you would have to save it in this store by JavaScript and as everybody can read your source code in the browser, its even more obvious.

The only possibilty to do such things safely is Server-Sided, like with PHP for example. If you though want the feeling of interactive behaviour, you can use AJAX on clientside to interact with the backend.

EDIT:
Ah, I think I got you wrong as you are talking about Java in Backend? If yes I think there is no Problem when u have the key hardcoded in your compiled sources??? If you want to store it somewhere else and are afraid someone uses it, you could salt and hash it in your application before you use it for key generation (of course the salt is hardcoded then)?

Comment: I'm using JSF so the key is in my source...I don't think the browser's see it. But I'm new to this so I'm not sure.